# Minimum, Maximum, and average of grades

Tags: java

I am trying to write a program that takes in grade numbers and returns the letter grade, and after the user enters -1 it returns the maximum grade, minimum grade, and the average grade that was entered. Right now, the program returns the letter grade and zero for the Average, maximum, and, minimum.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class getLetterGrade {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int count = getGrades();
        int sum = getGrades();
        int max =  getGrades();
        int min =  getGrades();
        System.out.println("You entered " + count + " students");
        System.out.println("Class average =" + sum / count);
        System.out.println("Maximum =" + max);
        System.out.println("Minimum ="+ min);

    }

    public static int getGrades() {
        Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in); {
        int count = 0;
        int sum = 0;
        int min = 100;
        int max = 0;

        while(true) {
            System.out.println("Welcome to the grade calculator. \n Please enter a numeric grade. \n After the last student in the class, enter a grade of -1.");


            int grade = reader.nextInt();



            if (grade >= 90) {
                System.out.println("That's an A");
            } else if (grade >= 80 ) {
                System.out.println("That's a B");
            } else if (grade >= 70) {
                System.out.println("That's a C");
            } else if (grade >= 60) {
                System.out.println("That's a D");
            } else if (grade >= 0) {
                System.out.println("That's an F");
            } else if (grade == -1) {
                return count; 
            }

            if (grade < min){
              min = grade;
            }
            if (grade > max){
              max = grade;}

            count++;
            sum += grade;

        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: I suspect you don't actually want to call `getGrades()` 4 times. Also `getGrades` does not return anything. Might be worth seeking some help from your professor/TA. This is a pretty fundamental lack of Java/programming knowledge

Answer (score 0):

In your main function, look at how you are trying to get count, sum, max, and min. How can `getGrades()` give you any of those values if `getGrades()` only returns count only when you get a -1?

Then you're also calling `getGrades()` four times. Do you need to ask for user input those 4 times?

Fix it by calling `getGrades()` only once, then move the print statements to be after your while loop in `getGrades()`.

Also change `getGrades()` so that it doesn't return anything, and just make it break out of the while loop when the user inputs -1.

Like others have said, I implore you to go talk to a professor, ta, or whatever to help explain this to you in person.

```
public static void getGrades() {
    Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in); 
    int count = 0;
    int sum = 0;
    int min = 100;
    int max = 0;

    while(true) {
        System.out.println("Welcome to the grade calculator. \n Please enter a numeric grade. \n After the last student in the class, enter a grade of -1.");

        int grade = reader.nextInt();

        if (grade >= 90) {
            System.out.println("That's an A");
        } else if (grade >= 80 ) {
            System.out.println("That's a B");
        } else if (grade >= 70) {
            System.out.println("That's a C");
        } else if (grade >= 60) {
            System.out.println("That's a D");
        } else if (grade >= 0) {
            System.out.println("That's an F");
        } else if (grade == -1) {
            // Exit while loop to finish the rest of the code
            break; 
        }

        if (grade < min){
          min = grade;
        }
        if (grade > max){
          max = grade;
        }

        count++;
        sum += grade;
    }
    // Moved print statements here, to be just outside the while loop
    System.out.println("You entered " + count + " students");
    System.out.println("Class average =" + sum / count);
    System.out.println("Maximum =" + max);
    System.out.println("Minimum ="+ min);
}
```